# Understanding applejpeg crash

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

My application is crashing from a number of different places, the only thing in common with all the crashes is the global trace buffer. Which is always like this :

```
7.047307     AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184318f28[0x157904800] Decoding completed without errors
7.048656     AppleJPEG                  0x00000001843170c0 [0x157904800] Options: 225x300 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
7.048656     AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184316f78 [0x157904800] Decoding: C0 0x00E1012C 0x000F304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 4947
7.095140     AppleJPEG                  0x000000018431626c [0x157904800] Created session
7.101648     AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184318f28 [0x1578f3600] Decoding completed without errors
7.104545     AppleJPEG                  0x00000001843170c0 [0x1578f3600] Options: 300x300 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
7.104545     AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184316f78 [0x1578f3600] Decoding: C0 0x012C012C 0x0013304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 6298
7.218370     AppleJPEG                  0x000000018431626c [0x1578f3600] Created session
7.310743     AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184318f28 [0x157101600] Decoding completed without errors
7.312623     AppleJPEG                  0x00000001843170c0 [0x157101600] Options: 300x298 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
7.312623     AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184316f78 [0x157101600] Decoding: C0 0x012C012A 0x0013304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 9699
7.372678     AppleJPEG                  0x000000018431626c [0x157101600] Created session
7.508725     AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184318f28 [0x157108a00] Decoding completed without errors
7.509980     AppleJPEG                  0x00000001843170c0 [0x157108a00] Options: 300x296 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
```

I have no idea how to approach this problem, what does global trace buffer mean ? and how is it different from thread backtraces ? what is the appleJPEG framework for and why could it be causing crashes ? am I looking in the wrong place, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace of one the the crashes?

Comment: @Losiowaty The stack trace for 2 of the crashes: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f3u5rbvljp6yv7t/AACKanM0zSWP6fYgi0D2TLjsa?dl=0

Comment: @Losiowaty thank you for taking the time to respond, I was beginning to lose faith in stackoverflow

Comment: No problem, but an hour long (at the time when I posted a comment) is quite a short time here on SO I would say, you just need to be patient ;) also can you please edit your question and paste in the stack trace? It is discouraged to provide information in links, as they may get outdated in the future.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am seeing something similar in my app.

Comment: @OmarEyadAbubaker, Do you have any solution?